# What is the best way to set global settings for Safari app extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-app-extension

As this official [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safariextensionsettings) said, I put `safari.extension.settings.test = "test"` in my injected script, and it didn't work with an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'safari.extension.settings.test = "test"')
```

And I noticed that this setting api might have been depreciated? [apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106731)

So what's the best way now to read/write global settings through the injected script or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Safari Extensions API is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions)!
Please check the [Safari App Extensions API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension) instead.

The easiest way would be to store your settings in `UserDefaults`, like a classic iOS/Mac app.